# Pegar o maior valor de uma coluna Mysql

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma coluna onde armazena os valores:

```
Nome | Turma | Nota1 | Nota2 | Nota3 | Nota4
```

Como eu faria para pegar a maior nota dos campos Nota1, Nota2, Nota3 e Nota4? Entendo que o MAX() faz isso, mas como eu poderia aplicar na minha necessidade?

Comment: Olá Fox.11, conseguiu resolver o problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o `CASE WHEN` pra resolver seu problema, realizando a consulta da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT Nome, Turma,
CASE
       WHEN Nota1 >= Nota2 AND Nota1 >= Nota3 THEN Nota1
       WHEN Nota2 >= Nota1 AND Nota2 >= Nota3 THEN Nota2
       WHEN Nota3 >= Nota1 AND Nota3 >= Nota2 THEN Nota3
       ELSE                                        Nota4
END AS MaiorNota
FROM *suaTabela*
```

Você também pode usar o comando GREATEST passando a quantidade de parâmetros para ser retornado o maior valor, por exemplo:

```
SELECT Nome, Turma, GREATEST(Nota1, Nota2, Nota3, Nota4) AS MaiorNota FROM *suaTabela*
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Olá André. Perfeito! Usei a sua primeira solução. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Fico feliz em poder ajudá-lo. Sucesso grande!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT GREATEST(Nota1, Nota2, Nota3, Nota4) FROM tabela WHERE id=1
```